# Can one pursue humanistic goals while being a successful entrepreneur?

Tags: ethics, practical-ethics

I have read books from Erich Fromm and others and I gathered understanding of what a human being is capable of (in a good way). In relation to work, it's being creative, in the true sense of the word. I could imagine my own purpose being in fostering this. Is being an entrepreneur the right way for me?

Comment: Welcome. The question is very broad. If you could make it more specific, some particular question about something Fromm wrote, that would help people provide an answer that isn't only an opinion.

Comment: An entrepreneur is just a person who starts businesses from the beginning founded on some financially stable footing.  It can be against the benefit of some groups or for them, so is not in conflict with humanistic goals.  An example is recycling plastics, which has good human benefits as well as financial ones.

Comment: The Buddhist idea of Right Livelihood addresses this https://www.huffingtonpost.com/lewis-richmond/right-livelihood-is-consc_b_832298.html

Comment: The title of the question (_Can one ...?_) is inconsistent with the body (_... for me?_) The title (_one..._) makes @PeterJens’ comment the only reasonable, though somewhat trivial, answer. The body (_me_) makes it unanswerable, the reason it was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too general. None of us knows you, so how are we supposed to give specific advice here?

I think I might be able to give you some insights instead:

The right profession for you is one that gives you joy doing it. It's the job that you don't need reasons to do because you just enjoy doing it.
This joy can be derived from many things. It can be because it's your nature, or it's even already your hobby, it can be because it gives you a feeling of meaning and sense.

If humanism is an important concern in your life, of course it may influence the question which jobs give you joy and which don't, and as such it will influence your choices.

However, ... even the most successful entrepreneurship in a humanistic field can be wrong for you if it's only a mental choice which doesn't give you immediate joy in your heart. If it doesn't give you joy, most of all you're unlikely to excel, thus making little impact in the first place.

You should consider this: As a truly happy person you contribute more to the well-being of the world than any unhappy humanistic person.
Don't try to make anyone happy if you aren't happy. It's like trying to make a gift that you don't have, it will never work. You can only give what you have, and if your humanism is rooted in unhappiness, what you'll spread is unhappiness.

Hence the prime concern should be your own happiness first. Don't confuse this with just satisfaction or egocentrism. Happiness is far beyond that.

Then from that point you will create a certain type of wealth naturally, most likely also by doing the profession that you are doing with heart and soul. It may be as an entrepreneur, but it doesn't have to be. That wealth that you create then you can spend on humanistic purposes, or you can invest the time that you have from having created this wealth for pursuing a humanistic project.

Comment: This is more a suitable answer to my situation, than an good answer to an exact expressed question could be. I definitely get your point. This helps me. I would love to rate this answer, maybe soon i will! ;)